# Replace a multiple left-join by a forloop

Tags: postgresql, loops, join

I have a table with points each with a time-attribute (column "hour") lying in different squares of a grit (marked by the column "gridid").

For each square i want to get the number of points lying within grouped by hour, thus getting a table with 24 columns + as many rows as existing gridid's.

So far i did that with 24 leftjoins (below). Is there a way with an simple loop to simplify the query?

```
SELECT * from (select gridid, count(id)  as "00" from points where hour = 0 GROUP BY gridid ORDER BY "00" DESC)t00 

left join
(select gridid, count(id)  as "01" from points where hour = 1 GROUP BY gridid)t01
on t01.gridid = t00.gridid

left join
(select gridid, count(id)  as "02" from points where hour = 2 GROUP BY gridid)t02
on t02.gridid = t00.gridid

...

left join
(select gridid, count(id)  as "24" from points where hour = 24 GROUP BY gridid)t02
on t02.gridid = t24.gridid
```

Answer (score 1):

FOR loops are generally a bad idea in SQL, which works better with set-based operators. Instead, try something like:

```
select grid_id,
       sum(case hour when 0 then 1 end) as "00",
       sum(case hour when 1 then 1 end) as "01",
       sum(case hour when 2 then 1 end) as "02",
...

       sum(case hour when 24 then 1 end) as "24"
from points 
group by grid_id
order by 2 desc
```

(Incidentally, columns 00 and 24 are unlikely to both be populated, unless you are using a 25-hour day.)

Comment: thank yoo, that might shorten the query, but imagine i would have to do a similar thing with 365 days of a year.

Comment: @Berlin_J: Why? Your question related to hours of the day, not days of the year - how are days of the year relevant? **If** they are relevant, please can you update your question to reflect the question you want **answered**, rather than the question you **asked**?

Comment: I'm just wondering how i can generally avoid those chains. I only mentioned the example with 365 days to emphasize what i want to improve in my query. How you see above, i already had a circumstantial solution before i wrote my question...

Comment: @Berlin_J: Unlike your original query, the query in my answer does **not** chain multiple selects together - it is a **single** query with multiple `case` statements. If you have a large set of values (eg. 365 days) that you want to summarise, it makes more sense to group by the summarisation criterion (eg. day), so that they are returned on a separate row for each group.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I concur that it is almost always a bad idea to replace a join of any kind with a for loop.  PostgreSQL will use a loop when it is the most appropriate method of joining.  In particular, a FOR loop gives you nothing that a normal join doesn't and it means micromanaging the planner in a job the planner can do perfectly well on its own.

Now in your case, you don't want a loop.  You have three options.

1. You can use CASE the way Mark Bannister suggests above.A
2. You can just return a set and pivot it in your client.  Something like

   ```
      SELECT grid_id, count(id), hour 
        FROM points
    GROUP BY grid_id, hour
    ORDER BY grid_id, hour;
   ```
3. You can use the `crosstab()` function in the `tablefunc` to pivot the above query in
   PostgreSQL.  This can take some practice but consult the tablefunc documentation for 
   how to do it.